# Reusable Workflow - Associated Column change, now error

Tags: workflow

I created a reusable workflow with associated site columns. Everything was working great. I then decided to add another function to the workflow, which required me to add a new associated column to the workflow. Once that happened, my original associated column somehow became corrupt because the workflow no longer works, even after removing the new/added functionality.

So, I'm looking for information on why associated columns in a workflow would become corrupt when a new associated column is added, even if the original associated columns are not modified in any way. I've also tried various troubleshooting steps of deleting and recreating, but nothing is working. I'm trying not to go back to square 1, but at this point it looks like I'm going to need to recreate everything - site columns, workflow and task list - which is beyond ridiculous. Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!